# How to automate superuser creation for my django project on first migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am creating super user with command `python manage.py createsuperuser`

I would like to set an email, password and create a superuser while running my first migrations.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: `python manage.py createsuperuser` you already said how to do that

Comment: Django superuser does ask for email and password? I'm confused on to what you are asking for?

Comment: You should run your first migration right away to set up your sql lite right away.

Comment: i want to automate superuser creation on my first db migration.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with creating a superuser in an automated way is that you'll have to hard-code the password into your source code, which is considered a bad practice. However, if you don't forget to change it immediately after logging in, it won't be that bad.

You can add a custom python code to your migration file with the [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython).

Suppose you have an app called `core`. You can either edit an existing migration (that was not yet applied on the server) or add a new one (I'll go with the second option).

```
python manage.py makemigrations core --empty
```

Now in the created file add the `RunPython` entry:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations


def create_superuser(apps, editor):
    User = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    User.objects.create_superuser('superuser@example.com', 'changethispassword')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_superuser, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```